# Detecting idle time in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

How to detect idle time in Corona? How to detect there is no user interaction or event with the device in a particular interval of time?The application what I am developing is based on user events.If the user doesn't provide any event for few minutes,the screen must be reloaded?Any idea about this with a sample code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up some counter which will count the idle time (maybe every second)...
When user touch the screen this timer will be set back to 0 - so when this counter reach some value (for example 60) then reload you page...

This is counter:

```
local idletime = 0
local function countidle()
    idletime = idletime + 1
        if idletime == 60 then
               -- Code for restart
        end
end
timer.performWithDelay(1000, countidle, 0)
```

Then do some function which will reset idletime value on touch...

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a screen tap listener:

```
local function onScreenTap( event )
   idletime =0
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "tap", onScreenTap )
```